react app deployed on gh-pages giving blank white screen
I am working on a small react app/website as part of my learning practice. I tried to host it on github pages. I followed the below procedure. The app is working in local but after hosting on gihub pages its giving blank screen with no console errors.
Login.js which i added a route (path="/") for in App.js
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import './Login.css';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'; // Import useNavigate

function Login() {

    const [firstname, setFirstname] = useState('');
    const [lastname, setLastname] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    
  
    const handleLogin = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      // Handle login logic here (e.g., call API or update state)
      console.log('First Name:', firstname);
      console.log('Last Name:', lastname);
      navigate('/home');
    };
  
    return (
      <div className="login-screen">
            <header className="header">
                <h1>Project Social</h1>
            </header>
            <main className="main-content">
                <form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="firstname">First Name</label>
                    <input
                        type="firstname"
                        id="firstname"
                        value={firstname}
                        onChange={(e) => setFirstname(e.target.value)}
                        required
                    />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="lastname">Last Name</label>
                    <input
                        type="lastname"
                        id="lastname"
                        value={lastname}
                        onChange={(e) => setLastname(e.target.value)}
                        required
                    />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                    <input
                        type="password"
                        id="password"
                        value={password}
                        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                        required
                    />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit">Login</button>
                </form>
                <p><a href="#">Forgot your password?</a></p>
                <p>Don't have an account? <a href="#">Sign up</a></p>
            </main>
      </div>
    );
  }

export default Login;

Login.css
.login-screen {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
  }

  .header {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

  .header h1 {
    margin: 0;
    color: #333;
  }
  
  .main-content {
    max-width: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  }

  .form-group {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  
  .form-group label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  
  .form-group input {
    width: 95%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  
  button {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #007bff;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  
  button:hover {
    background-color: #0056b3;
  }

I used the below steps to build and deploy it on gh-pages:
Ran below command

npm install gh-pages --save-dev

Added below line in package.json
"homepage": "https://sainath27.github.io/project_social_app"
Updated scripts object in package.json with below lines:
"predeploy":"npm run build",
"deploy":"gh-pages -d build",
And ran below command

npm run deploy

Build branch: gh-pages
Pages Website: https://sainath27.github.io/project_social_app/
repo: https://github.com/sainath27/project_social_app
it is expected to show login kinda webpage asking for name & password.

Try to add
"homepage": "https://sainath27.github.io/project_social_app/"

to package.json

it is already available.

Based on my research I found a solution. When i used HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter and re-deployed on gh-pages. the site is working/loading.
Dont know what the reason is

Based on my research I found a solution. When i used HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter and re-deployed on gh-pages, the site is working/loading. Dont know what is the reason behind. will update once i know it.
